# Firebird 2.5 reports "is not a valid database" although it is

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

I've got two computers both running Firebird (let's called them A and B) and two database files (let's call them a.fdb and b.fdb), both copied to both computers. On B I get the message

> b.fdb is not a valid database
>   The other files work, on A both files work.

This would be easy to explain, if B was an older version, but it's a newer one (it was FB 2.1, and because of this problem I installed FB 2.5). The files a.fdb and b.fdb have ODS 11.1 and 10.1, respectively. It looks like new versions of FB wouldn't support ODS 10.1 anymore, which I can't believe. But I see no other explanation, can you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to make backup and restore of database.

Comment: I made a backup using A, tried restore using B, got an error message, added the option -FIX_FSS_METADATA utf8, and it works. Thx.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem with an old database.

In my case even the gbak command presented the "is not a valid database". (I also tried with the FIX_FSS_METADATA option)

I found that if the database was created in an 32bits environment it can't be opened in a 64bits one.

So, what I had to do was:

- Create a VM with a 32bits environment (in my case I created a VM with Windows XP)
- Copy the database to this VM and make a backup using GBAK
- Copy the backup file to my machine (64bits)
- Run a restore using GBAK

After all this I could open the database again.

Hope it helps!

Comment: As a reference: [similar problem and solution](https://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/topic,23666.msg142499.html#msg142499)

Answer (score 3):

In my case I can't open a database whose was created in 32 bits in a 64 bits, so try to install firebird in 32 bits

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yupe, this solution helped me. I uninstalled the 64bit and install the 32bit. problem solved.