# Statement failed, SQLSTATE = -922 my_database.gdb is not a valid database

Tags: database, database-connection, firebird

I just can't connect to Firebird on Ubuntu.

Through the terminal I do:

```
 rafaeljesus@ubuntu:/tmp$ isql-fb 
Use CONNECT or CREATE DATABASE to specify a database
SQL> connect .my_database.gdb user sysdba password masterkey;
Statement failed, SQLSTATE = -922
file /tmp/cnes.gdb is not a valid database
```

Searching on the web I realized that this occurs when the file is corrupted, which is not the case ... I do not know if this is because the file is in gdb. instead of fdb..I do not know about Firebird ...

I really need some help.

Comment: File extensions don't matter, those are just conventions

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862392/firebird-2-5-reports-is-not-a-valid-database-although-it-is

Answer (score 5):

As you don't specify any version information, ODS version of the database, if you upgraded the Firebird version, or whether this database was moved from another system etc I provide some options:

- The database was created on a 32 bit platform and now moved to a 64 bit platform without backup/restore: older file structures of Firebird (at least ODS 10 from Firebird 1.0 and InterBase 6) are specific to the bitness of the platform: a backup on the 32 bit platform and a restore on the 64 bit platform should suffice
- The database was created on a big-endian platform and now moved to a little-endian platform without backup/restore

NOTE: In both cases make sure you create a transportable backup (it is the default, but check).

- Another option could be that a restore of the database failed before the full database was restored. Check your restore log and address any errors (see [Firebird 2.5 reports "is not a valid database" although it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862392/firebird-2-5-reports-is-not-a-valid-database-although-it-is) for a suggestion )

If all else fail: contact a Firebird/Interbase recovery/repair company like IB Surgeon.

Comment: Hi Mark tanks a lot, I´ll check out about all of yours suggestions. You are right the database was crate on a 32 bit Windowns XP (Firebird 1.5) and I´ve tried on Ubuntu 10.04 64bits the Firebird 2.1, 2.5 and no success, so thats why its just works on 32 bits plataform, I´ve installed Virtual Box and XP 32 bits on it and it worked..I aint´t got no time now, will try to backup on XP and restore on Ubuntu 2nite...I´ll let ya know about´it...cheers